# How to save outputs of a expect script to a file

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I am trying to save the outputs (multiple lines from one command) of a bash command that has been executed by a expect script into a file or variable that I can use outside of the expect script. What I used to do before was tee into a file:

```
expect <<-EOS |& tee log.${hostname}.log
        #!/usr/bin/expect
        set timeout $EXP_TIMEOUT
        ...
```

or use the log_file command:

```
expect <<-EOS
        #!/usr/bin/expect
        set timeout $EXP_TIMEOUT
        log_file -a -noappend log.${hostname}.log
        spawn sh
        expect "$prompt"
        ...
```

This would normally work however I'm now triggering a expect script from another expect script. Expect Script 1: SSH's into a remote server and executes the second Expect script. Expect is used in script 1 as it has to enter in a password.

Expect Script 2: This is a script executed from the local server via expect. Script 2 is an expect script because a password is required to execute the command. A copy of script 2's expect component can be found below.

Expect Script 2 Sample:

```
expect <<-EOS
        #!/usr/bin/expect
        set timeout $EXP_TIMEOUT
        log_file -a -noappend log.${hostname}.log
        spawn sh
        expect "$prompt"
        send -- "$cmd\r"
        expect "*assword"
        send -- "$mcasPassword\r"
        #output is printed on the remote console after the password is sent
        expect {
                "*rror*" {
                puts "\nAn issue was faced\n"
                exit 1
                }
                "$prompt" {
                exit 0
                }
        }
        expect eof
EOS
```

After the password is sent, multiple lines of output is printed out and I wanted it to be either captured in a file or a variable that could be used in other functions present within the bash script.

When I execute script 2 on the remote server by manually ssh's into it, it works perfectly.

Any advice on how I could achieve this or what the issue here is would be highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To write to a file, use this Tcl procedure:

```
proc writeToFile {filename string} {
    set f [open $filename "w"]
    puts -nonewline $f $string
    close $f
}

# For example, use it like this:
set toSave "Hello, World!"
writeToFile "hello.txt" $toSave
```

To read it back in, use this Tcl procedure:

```
proc readFromFile {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f
    return $data
}

# To continue our example:
set loadedBack [readFromFile "hello.txt"]
```

If you're saving out multiple variables, consider putting them in an array. Then you can save it like this:

```
writeToFile "saved_array.data" [array get theArray]
```

and load them back like this:

```
array set theArray [readFromFile "saved_array.data"]
```

There are *many* more options for this sort of thing, including saving stuff as scripts that you can `source`, serializing things as JSON, and writing things to an SQLite database.

Comment: If the writing and reading sides are on different machines, things get _very_ complicated, as the complexities of file transfer and/or networked filesystems come into play. There are a very large number of considerations.

Comment: Hi thanks @Donal Fellows , if I were to simply want to record the outputs on the console after the "send -- "$mcasPassword\r"" line until the next "prompt", how would I go about doing that? I'm unsure as to where I would put your 'write to file' code into my expect script.

Comment: Also in addition, @Donal Fellows , in this case writing to file is more crucial as I can then use Bash commands to manage the file appropriately. I don't need to read a file's content through tcl as of yet.